# sql merge two table and format

Tags: mysql, sql, db2

TABLE SRN

| id | ACC | DEPART |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | IT |
| 2 | A | FINANCE |
| 3 | A | AEROSPACE |
| 4 | B | IT |
| 5 | B | FINANCE |
| 6 | B | AEROSPACE |

Table TRN

| id | ACC | IT POPULATION | FINANCE POPULATION | AEROSPACE POPULATION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 10 | 20 | 30 |
| 2 | B | 95 | 105 | 110 |

FINAL RESULT

| ACC | DEPART | IT POPULATION | FINANCE POPULATION | AEROSPACE POPULATION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | IT | 10 | 0 | 0 |
| A | FINANCE | 0 | 20 | 0 |
| A | AEROSPACE | 0 | 0 | 30 |
| B | IT | 95 | 0 | 0 |
| B | FINANCE | 0 | 105 | 0 |
| B | AEROSPACE | 0 | 0 | 110 |

How can I format the tables to get the final result. I tried using left join but not sure how to  change the format to the desired result.

Comment: Please publish your query.

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Use conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `left join` with `case`:

```
select s.acc, 
       s.depart,
       case when s.depart = "IT" then t.it_pop else 0 end `IT POPULATION`,
       case when s.depart = "FINANCE" then t.fin_pop else 0 end `FINANCE POPULATION`,
       case when s.depart = "AEROSPACE" then t.aer_pop else 0 end `AEROSPACE POPULATION`
from srn s left join trn t on s.acc = t.acc;
```